# Android Studio cannot resolve symbol 'equals'

Tags: android, android-studio

I was trying to make a quiz app, that would change the question every time you submit, and it should work except for .equals doesn't work, and it cannot resolve the symbol.

[image]

its crazy! Any nelp would be apreciated

Comment: Clean your project and rebuild it.

Comment: sync project with Gradle files

Comment: wired issue --  Did you try to File-> Invalidate Cache And Restart option in android studio

Comment: You can paste code here directly

Comment: i rebuilt, synced, and invalidateed cache, all didnt work

Comment: this question is very low quality because you have screen shot your code.  I am voting for this to be closed; please edit your post and remove the image and paste your code into a code block to improve your chances for my vote to be rejected.

Comment: u know, i dont care if this is low quality, i just want an answer, so plz stop hating and if u arnt going to answer, go somewhere else

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have added above `code` portion outside of a `Method`**(`life-cycle` callback method `or` your `own` method)** that's why you are getting error:

> `cannot resolve symbol 'equals'`.

**SOLUTION:**

Just move your `code` portion inside a `method`. Here is an example:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);

    ..........
    .................

    int QuizSelection = 20;
    Intent gotosetone = getIntent();
    Intent gotosetone2 = getIntent();
    String randomintent1 = gotosetone.getStringExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    String randomintent2 = gotosetone2.getStringExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    if (randomintent1.equals("Quiz One")){
        QuizSelection = 1;
    } else if (randomintent2.equals("Quiz Two")){
        QuizSelection = 2;
    }

    ...........
    ..................
}
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: i could do this, but then there would be an error and i couldnt use any of the variaables such as randomintent1, and gotosetone inside my onclick